# What is more effective (in particular, in C): moving an array element or deleting it and creating it in a new place?

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-arrays

I am learning the C language and as I am learning it, I encountered the question.

How best to make the next change in the array:

I have an array of structs. Array's size changes quite frequently. In particular, I need to remove the last element of it and create an new element with [0] index, changing the content of the structure (the structures contain coordinates, I need to change these coordinates).

Would it make any difference if I moved the last element to the place of [0] index, moving the array's elements forward, e. g., using memmove() function instead of deleting the last element and creating a new one with [0] index (also, as I understand I need here too "compress" the array on 1 element to the forward using the memmove() function?)?

Or does it not matter? Maybe there is a way to do it better (in particular, I am interested in C or C++ (more specifically, C subset)).

If you need any clarification, please let me know and I will try to explain it in more detail.

Thank you for your attention!

**UPDATE (for better understanding).**

Array contains structs containing 2 integer variables x and y (coords).
What should I do with "array":

1. To be able to remove the last element - this will have to be done often.
2. Parallel to (1), I need to add a new element to the begin - "the head". That’s the crux of the question - I can just change the coordinates of the last element, move it to the beginning. Either create a new element with a new structure and simply remove the last element.
3. Also sometimes "array" will increase, i.e. a new structure will be added. This happens regardless of (1) and (2) points.

Comment: Assuming you want to use C ... is the array size bounded? For example if you know that the maximum size of the array is 20 items then you could implement this as a fixed 20-item array in a ring, and simply maintain start/end indexes to the positions of the first and last items. You would be able to avoid large memmoves by simply modifying the start/end indexes (mod N). To move the last item to the start of the list, simply copy it into the start-1 (mod N) position and decrement both start and end, again mod N.

Comment: If you need to remove items at the end and insert items at the front often, you could use a [deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue). C++'s standard lib already has `std::deque<T>`. In C, you can implement it as a circular buffer, where instead of moving everything around when you insert, you move the start index of the buffer. (You will have to write access functions and lose the access via `a[i]`.)

Comment: @jarmod, I propose to use a dynamic array, because size will also change quite frequently.

Comment: @M Oehm, Does this involve not only moving the element, but also adding new elements to the end? And will it be faster or more economical than just a dynamic array?

Comment: "C is a subset of C++" may have been true in the mid 90's.  It is no longer. They are different languages.

Comment: Contrary to what jarmod said, a circular buffers can change its capacity. When you want to add an element at the beginning, you have to move all elements one place up. In a deque, you just put the element at slot `a[n - 1]` and declare n − 1 the new start, so that in stead of counting 0, 1, 2,  3, ..., the array internally uses n − 1, 0, 1, 2, ... You don't expose the new start, though and need functions like `get_at(arr, i)`. On each lookup, the circular logic will take a bit more time, but inserting new items at the beginning ist fast, because nothing need to be copied, except the new item.

Comment: @William Pursell, Thank you! What I meant was that there could be an answer to C++, but not using the C++ features, but what is in the pure C too.

Comment: @M Oehm, Just in case, for a better understanding, I’ll update my answer and tell you what I need to do with the array. Please, check the updated text of my question.

Comment: I think my understanding of what you want is quite good. You are the one who refuses to understand. `:)` A circular buffer is the right data structure here. Why don't you give it a try.

Comment: Martin, thank you very much! :) You have helped me, but confess, I have never heard of such a thing and therefore I am afraid to make it myself :D But I hope it works and I'll deal. 
P.S. Would you like to create an answer? Then I can mark it as resolved and close the question if there won't be another answers.

Comment: If you need to move elements a lot, it may be better to use a doubly-linked list, but that is no good if you need "random access" to elements as opposed to "sequential access" from either end.

Comment: Is it possible to implement the idea of a circular buffer using dynamic memory? Because I don't know how many structures I will add. 
P.S. I am trying to write simple implementation of "Snake" game and structs are SDL_Rect structures (SDL2 library).

Comment: Sure, you can make your circular buffer dynamic. Try it with a fixed size first and don't allow overflow. If that works, make it dynamic: If you have, for example, `2301` and add one more element, you can double the size and move the "wrapped" elements to the end: `23....01`. Snake is, of course, the poster child for circular buffers. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you and all the best, @M Oehm!
P.S. and you can create the answer - you help me to solve my problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe – frequent operations at both ends of an array – is a typical use case for a double-ended queue, or [deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue). The C++ standard library has `std::deque<T>`. In C, you can implement a deque as a circular buffer.

Imagine you have an array of a fixed size. Apart from the size, the array also has a length, the number of valid values in the array. You can now push and pop elements at the end:

```
[. . . . . . . .]       length = 0
[0 . . . . . . .]       push(arr, 0)      arr[length++] = 0
[0 1 . . . . . .]       push(arr, 1)      arr[length++] = 1
[0 1 2 . . . . .]       push(arr, 2)      arr[length++] = 2
[0 1 . . . . . .]       x = pop(arr)      x = arr[--length]0
```

Now, if you want to add or remove element at the front, you have to shift the remaining elements. A circular buffer does something different: When you insert an element at the start, you fill the "gap" (the dots) from the right and you keep the start index. That way, the array wraps:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 . . .]       ^: start index
 ^                                           // seen as:
[0 1 2 3 4 . . a]       unshift(arr, a)      // [a, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
               ^
[0 1 2 3 4 . b a]       unshift(arr, b)      // [b, a, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
             ^
[0 1 2 3 4 . . a]       x = shift(arr)       // == b
               ^
```

In this buffer, you will not access the elements directly with `arr[i]`. You need access functions that will do the wrappig logic behind the scenes.

You can make the deque allocate more memory as it grows. An example implementation is below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



typedef struct Queue Queue;
typedef unsigned Item;

#define enforce(COND, MSG) \
    if (COND); else exit((fprintf(stderr, "Fatal :" MSG "\n"), 1))

struct Queue {
    size_t length;
    size_t size;
    size_t start;
    Item *item;
};

/* 
 *      Create queue object
 */
Queue *queue_create(void)
{
    Queue *q = calloc(1, sizeof(*q));

    return q;
}

/*
 *      Destroy queue object
 */
void queue_destroy(Queue *q)
{
    if (q) {
        free(q->item);
        free(q);
    }
}

/* 
 *      Internal: re-allocate
 */
static void queue_grow(Queue *q)
{
    if (q->length >= q->size) {
        size_t old_size = q->size;
        
        q->size = (old_size) ? 2 * old_size : 16;
        
        q->item = realloc(q->item, q->size * sizeof(*q->item));        
        enforce(q->item, "Allocation failed!");
            
        memcpy(q->item + q->start + old_size,
               q->item + q->start,
               (old_size - q->start) * sizeof(*q->item));
        q->start += old_size;
    }
}

/*
 *      Add an item at the end
 */
void queue_push(Queue *q, Item item)
{
    queue_grow(q);
    
    q->item[(q->start + q->length++) % q->size] = item;
}

/*
 *      Remove the item at the end
 */
Item queue_pop(Queue *q)
{
    if (q->length) {
        return q->item[(q->start + --q->length) % q->size];
    }
    
    enforce(0, "Queue underflow!");
    
    return 0;
}

/*
 *      Add an item at the front
 */
void queue_unshift(Queue *q, Item item)
{
    queue_grow(q);
    
    if (q->start) {
        q->start--;
    } else {
        q->start = q->size - 1;
    }
    
    q->length++;
    q->item[q->start] = item;
}

/*
 *      Remove the item from the front
 */
Item queue_shift(Queue *q)
{
    Item item = q->item[q->start];
    
    q->length--;
    q->start++;
    if (q->start == q->size) q->start = 0;
    
    return item;
}

/*
 *      Get the item at index (Neg. index counts from the end)
 */
Item queue_at(const Queue *q, long long index)
{
    if (index < 0) index += q->length;

    enforce(0 <= index && index < q->length, "Bad index!");
    
    return q->item[(q->start + index) % q->size];    
}

/*
 *      Get a pointer to the item at index
 */
Item *queue_ref_at(const Queue *q, long long index)
{
    if (index < 0) index += q->length;

    if (index < 0 || index >= q->length) return 0;
    
    return (Item *) &q->item[(q->start + index) % q->size];    
}

/*
 *      Get the length of the queue
 */
size_t queue_length(const Queue *q)
{
    return q->length;
}



/*
 *      (Rather silly) Example
 */
int main(void)
{
    Queue *q = queue_create();
    
    unsigned sum = 0;
    unsigned i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        queue_push(q, i);
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        queue_unshift(q, -(1 + i));
    }
    
    printf("start: %d\n", queue_at(q, 0));      // -100
    printf("end: %d\n", queue_at(q, -1));       // 999
    
    unsigned *ref = queue_ref_at(q, -1);
    
    if (ref) *ref = 10000;
    printf("end: %d\n", queue_pop(q));    
    
    while (queue_length(q)) {
        sum += queue_shift(q);
    }

    printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
    
    queue_destroy(q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of `enforce`, consider `assert` in `assert.h`, may be more full-featured?

Comment: I thought of that, but then someone would have commented that assertions don't fire in non-debug builds. `:)` After all, allocation failure is somethng that should be caught. But the out-of-bound indices are programming errors and should be asserts. Anyway, it's just a short example.

Comment: On further inspection, yes, you are right; this has programming errors and environmental errors caught as one `enforce`. This is not codereview though; excellent answer.

Comment: Hello, @M Oehm! Now after the queue has been implemented with a circular buffer, I want to understand the implementation with linked lists. Can they be compared and in which situations should an each implementation be used?

Comment: An array is efficient when removing or inserting at the back. The circular buffer is efficient when removing or inserting at the front or back. Both are memory and cache efficient and are fast for indexed access. Removing or inserting in the middle (and at the front for array) is slow. A singly linked list is fast when inserting or removing at the front. Removing elements in the middle or at the end itself is fast, but finding these elements is usually slow. They are neither as memory nor as cache efficient as arrays.

Comment: Therer are other differences. For example pointers from the outside to array/buffer elements can be invalidated when the array is shifted or re-allocated. Pointers to list nodes stay intact. In general, prefer arrays for many items. Linked lists are good when they are short and when they have to be re-linked often. Sometimes, an algorithm lends itself to a linked-list implementation, but the workhorse for linear data is the array, I think.

Comment: Dear @M Oehm,
I’m sorry, but I’ve been getting it for a long time... but I’m trying to figure out how to work with algorithms and data structures. And I still have questions. When you say "array" do you mean just a dynamic array or is it related to a circular buffer? 
P.S. I have a pretty weak knowledge base, and I’m probably gonna do some kind of memo or schematic about data structures. Otherwise, I sometimes don’t know what it is or I don’t see the difference... Sorry, perseverance and stubborn incomprehension :(

Comment: To me an array is a contiguous block of memory, in C at its most basic a fixed-size C array like `int a[N];`. They are connected and related by their position in memory: `a[1]` comes right after`a[0]` and before `a[2]`. That's way you can index them fast, but removing from the middle leaves a gap and you have to move all elements to the right to fill the gap. (Dynamic arrays are the same, once you have `malloc` ed the memory. The circular buffer above uses an array, too, but it does some arithmetics on the index to calculate the acual index from the "perceived" index )

Comment: The elements of linked lists can be anywhere in memory. You cannot tell how they are related by looking at their memory addresses. Therefore, they need link pointers to each other. When you shuffle them around, you just shuffle the links.

Comment: But the comment section here isn't really the place to discuss that. There are many good books and online resources on data structures. I suggest implementing dynamic arrays and linked lists yourself and study how well they fare for different tasks. How fast are thay? How complex is the code? Lots of fun. `:)`

Comment: One more clarification, please. 
I don’t quite understand the work with adding an element to the beginning. Using the code from your answer I get not what I expect to see:

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7eRvX5dr (Sorry for the link, could not format a large text in the comment.)
I want unshift 15 and 15,but get 604.  This looks like adding only to the end (all new/deleted elements in the output are below and nowhere above). Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are not supposed to access the items with `q->item[index]`. Use `queue_at(q, index)` instead. Look at my illustration above: The 15's are where `a` and `b`are, at the end of the internal array. The user of the queue shouldn't see that array. (Of course, here everything in in one file and you can see it.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I just have to go and do something! And can you recommend a good topic book or better two :)?

Comment: Also two more questions have emerged... Why in "else" is 16 here: `q->size = (old_size) ? 2 * old_size : 16;`. And what size has circular buffer after creation? And why function pop is not void? What it returns? And why (In my mind, it’s just changing the queue it got).

Comment: No offence, but this is getting tedious. 16 is the default size. The `pop` function returns the removed element.

Comment: Yes, I feel you. Thank you and all the best!